# Error at the console with cake bake

Tags: php, xampp, cakephp-2.0

I installed XAMPP and cakephp 2.6.3. I configured the database default; in my application it works perfectly, but when I try to execute the command `cake bake all` in the shell I get this error:
[image]

Comment: hey man you need to set environment variable for this in your system and execute command on sell by reaching to the project folder.

Comment: This would almost certainly be better if you copied from the console and pasted the error message in instead of leaving the screenshot.

Comment: try to make it with the help of this link:-- http://nurelm.com/running-cakephp-command-line-tools-in-windows/